# How Do I Use the MoqAutoMocker that comes with StructureMap 2.5.3?

Tags: unit-testing, structuremap, moq

I'm trying to use the MoqAutoMocker class that comes with StructureMap and I can't find any examples of how it should be used.  All I have to go on is the [example at the StructureMap site that uses RhinoMocks](http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/AutoMocker.htm#section1).

What I'm trying to do is get reference to one of my auto-mocked/injected dependencies using the Get method.  According to that link above, I should be able to do something like this

```
    // This retrieves the mock object for IMockedService
    autoMocker.Get<IMockedService>().AssertWasCalled(s => s.Go());
```

Note how you can use AssertWasCalled, which inidcates that the Get function returns a reference to the RhinoMocks Mock object?  This same bit of code doesn't work for me when I use the MoqAutoMocker.

I have a class SignInController that depends upon an ISecurityService in the constructor.  Using the MoqAutoMocker like the RhinoAutoMocker is used in the example, I think I should be able to do this...

```
var autoMocker = new MoqAutoMocker<SignInController>();
autoMocker.Get<ISecurityService>().Setup(ss => ss.ValidateLogin
(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);
```

But the problem is that I never get access to the Setup method.  In this case, the call to autoMocker.Get seems to be returning an instance of ISecurityService and not Mock<ISecurityService>

Has anyone successfully used MoqAutoMocker this way?  Am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Did you figure it out ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recently ran into a simillar problem. It seems that the solution is to do something like this:

```
var autoMocker = new MoqAutoMocker<SignInController>();
var mock = autoMocker.Get<ISecurityService>();
Mock.Get(mock).Setup(ss => ss.ValidateLogin
(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);
```

I have also posted a lengthier example on my blog: [Setting Expectations With StructureMap’s MoqAutoMocker](http://joelabrahamsson.com/post/2009/09/17/Setting-Expectations-With-StructureMape28099s-MoqAutoMocker.aspx).

Comment: You rock.  This worked for me.  I had about given up on using the AutoMocker until I saw this.  Thanks!

Comment: I've written a [blog post](http://evolutionarydeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/automock-with-structuremap-and-moq.html) on the subject that uses `Mock.Get` wrapped in a handy base class.

Comment: Joel, your link above appears to be broken. The correct one is currently http://joelabrahamsson.com/entry/setting-expectations-with-structuremaps-moqautomocker

Answer (score 1):

`autoMocker.Get<ISecurityService>()` 

will return ISecurityService and you can't Setup on it. In contrary 

`Mock.Get(mock)`

will return Moq.Mock, then you could Setup on it.